# YAML pipeline: Execute task if RESOURCES_TRIGGERINGALIAS = "ui"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two pre-merge pipelines:

1. uipr
2. apipr

And one CI/CD pipeline:

1. Application

in the UI repo, whenever a PR is generated to the branch `main` the **uipr** will run. the same goes for the API repo and **apipr**.

If this pre PR run is successful, the `Application` pipeline will run.

The `Application` pipeline will populate the `resources.triggeringalias` variable which includes the name of the pre-merge pipeline that executed the CI: **uipr** / **apipr**

---

The `Application` pipeline also has two boolean parameters called **compileui** and **compileapi**, set to *false* by default. If I run the `Application` pipeline manually and set any of these to true it will execute the template to compile whichever was selected.

---

What I want to achieve is:

1. If `resources.triggeringalias` equals **uipr** OR `parameters.compileui` equals **true** then execute the template *compileui.yaml*
2. If `resources.triggeringalias` equals **apipr** OR `parameters.compileapi` equals **true** then execute the template *compileapi.yaml*

Here's what I have so far:

```
parameters:
- name: compileui
  displayName: compile ui
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: compileapi
  displayName: compile api
  type: boolean
  default: false

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: api
  - repository: ui
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: ui
      source: uipr
      trigger: true
    - pipeline: api
      source: apipr
      trigger: true

stages:
- stage: ci
  jobs:
  - job: ui
    steps:
    - checkout: ui
    - ${{ if or(eq(variables['resources.triggerinalias'], 'ui'),eq(parameters.compileui, true)) }}:
      - template: steps/build-ui.yaml
  - job: api
    steps:
    - checkout: api
    - ${{ if or(eq(variables['resources.triggeringalias'], 'api'),eq(parameters.compileapi, true)) }}:
      - template: steps/build-api.yaml
```

I know that the ***(variables['resources.triggeringalias'], 'ui')*** is only happening during runtime and not on template expansion. That is what I'm missing and don't know how to do it

Comment: Hello @Leo Liu-MSFT I'm about to test your proposed solution

I will let you know

thanks for helping!

Comment: FYI - typo in the script... missing a "g" - `resources.triggerinalias`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> YAML pipeline: Execute task if RESOURCES_TRIGGERINGALIAS = “ui”

You could use pipeline resource metadata as predefined variables `resources.pipeline.<Alias>.pipelineName` and parameters as condition on the job level：

```
- stage: ci
  jobs:
  - job: ui
    pool:
      vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
    condition: or(eq(variables['resources.pipeline.ui.pipelineName'], 'ui'), eq(${{parameters.compileui}}, true))
    steps:
      - template: steps/build-ui.yaml
```

You could check following references for some more details:

[The pipeline resource metadata as predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#the-pipeline-resource-metadata-as-predefined-variables)

[How to get previous build pipeline's build number in case of consecutive build pipelines?](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/3398#issuecomment-594635713)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it you want to have part of pipeline run only when pipeline was triggered by another pipeline or when it was run manually with marked parameter. You can achieve this with this:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: compileui
  displayName: compile ui
  type: boolean
  default: false

trigger: none
pr: none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: hadar   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: kmadof.hadar # Name of the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - releases/*
      - master

stages:
- stage: printer
  jobs:
  - job: printVariables
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "$(Build.Reason)"
        echo "Build run name was: $(resources.pipeline.hadar.runName)"
- ${{ if or(and(eq(parameters.compileui, true), eq(variables['build.reason'], 'Manual')), eq(variables['build.reason'], 'ResourceTrigger')) }}:
  - stage: ci
    condition: and(in(variables['build.reason'], 'Manual', 'ResourceTrigger'), succeeded())
    jobs:
    - job: ui
      steps:
      - script: echo "Hello from ci"
```

Comment: hello @Krzysztof-Madej I added some more information (to hopefully make it more clear), thanks for your reply